# Erro ao criar novo projeto em Angular

Tags: angular

Estou tentando criar um novo projeto via command line (ng new nome_projeto), porém, sempre da esse erro:

```
Installing packages (npm)...npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: students@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: jasmine-core@3.6.0
npm ERR! node_modules/jasmine-core
npm ERR!   dev jasmine-core@"~3.6.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer jasmine-core@">=3.7.1" from karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.6.0
npm ERR! node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter
npm ERR!   dev karma-jasmine-html-reporter@"^1.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\wesle\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\wesle\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-20T01_51_26_33
3Z-debug.log
× Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Obrigado pela atenção.

Att;

Wesley Jacques

Comment: Geralmente isso tem a ver com incompatibilidade de versões (node, npm, pacotes em geral)

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo. Realmente era isso, eu atualizei o node e dei o comando npm install -g @angular/cli e agora voltou a funcionar de novo.

Answer (score -1):

Abre o seu package.json e troca a versão do jasmine-core para "~3.7.1". Depois executa o *npm install* para baixar essa dependência e o projeto vai rodar certinho quando fizer o *ng serve*.